# Is it necessary to deploy the Ingress Controller using DaemonSet?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

That is my current solution:

LoadBalancer Instance with cloud -> Cluster NodePort Service -> Ingress Controller Service -> Ingress Controller Pod.

is it necessary to deploy the Ingress Controller using DaemonSet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a reasonably large cluster deploying ingress as deployment with multiple replicas is suitable compared to daemonset. When you are using deployment just make sure that replicas gets deployed in different nodes.You don't need a high number of NGINX instances to handle high volumes of traffic and most importantly, you need to keep in mind that each instance of the ingress controller needs to reach the kubernetes API server. This means if you have lots of replicas, you are putting (unnecessary) pressure. Using a deployment with an anti-affinity rule to avoid multiple replicas in the same node is, in most of the cases, more than enough

Comment: This answer sounds very familar.... https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/875 You should at least leave some credits, if you copy-paste answers.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, Deamonset is preferred for ingress controller instead of deployment. We had an issue lately where the ingress-controller was running via a deployment and one of the nodes didn't have this pod allocated. Due to the same reason, the node was listed as "unhealthy" in the loadbalancer targergroup healthcheck.

Even Nginx recommend Daemonset, though a properly managed deployment will do the same job.

> A DaemonSet schedules exactly one type of Pod per cluster node,
> masters included unless a node is configured to repel those Pods.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/

You may need to add taints and tolerations to exclude master nodes from daemonset as only worker need this pod running.

Comment: The fact that the nginx pod wasn't running on that node can't having anything to do with the node's health.